# Need to access images from other directory

Tags: angular, assets

I have a requirement where I need to access images from a folder outside my angular application directory. Now this gets even more complex with the requirement being that my application will be hosted somewhere while that directory containing the images will be somewhere else.
So I have two questions here :
1. Is there a way to do all this stuff locally? As in suppose I am running my angular application on the same computer as my directory of images which will be in some other folder than my application. For example, application might be in E:/myapp while images maybe in D:/images. So is there a way to do just that?
2. In this scenario we are having the images folder located on some other computer while angular app is hosted somewhere else. Is it possible to do so with only the path of that folder?

Please share your thoughts and implementations on this. I tried searching a lot. Closest solution I could get to was glob but I don't think even that is able to fulfill my requirement as it did not work in my case.

Comment: Angular applications run on a server and it doesn't have direct access to the local file system. Doesn't matter if you're running it local or remote. To access image remotely they need to be hosted elsewhere on the server and there must be some form of API in place to facilitate access to frontends (like the Angular app).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think there must be some solution. I will wait for some others to respond after which I will consider closing this question if there seems to be no solution